# java.util.NoSuchElementException occurs for some reason

Tags: java

I've run this code. Description, this code is about choosing a choice what to do. Error Occurs in  every input.next()

```
public static void showItem() throws IOException {
    deleteInformation delete = new deleteInformation();
    showInformation info = new showInformation();
    info.showAllItemInfo(); //Just show all item (No scanner here)

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("1.Delete an information | 2.Go back to previous | : ");
    int choice = 2;
    choice = input.nextInt();
    
    
    while(choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
        System.out.print("Please type between 1-2 : ");
        input.nextLine();
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
    if(choice == 1) {
        int wanted = 0;
        System.out.print("Please type what number you want to delete : ");
        wanted = input.nextInt();
        
        while(wanted < 1 || wanted > info.countAllItem()) {
            System.out.print("Please type between 1-" + info.countAllItem() + " : ");
            wanted = input.nextInt();
        }
        delete.deleteItemNum(wanted);
        chooseOption();
        
    }
    else {
        chooseOption();
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Then this is how an error occurs.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at LostItemService.showItem(LostItemService.java:216)
at LostItemService.chooseOption(LostItemService.java:130)
at LostItemService.main(LostItemService.java:8)
```

I tried to put input.nextLine(); on both before and after nextInt() But It didn't figured.
I am finding a way to fix it. Please help ;w;. Appreciate it.

About chooseOption method

```
public static void chooseOption() throws IOException {
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please choose what do you want to do");
    System.out.println("1.Put found item without any person information");
    System.out.println("2.Insert your lost item and your information");
    System.out.println("3.View existed information");
    System.out.println("4.Close this program");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    while(choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        System.out.print("Please type between 1-4 : ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    
    if(choice == 1) {
        saveItem();
    }
    else if(choice == 2) {
        savePerson();
    }
    else if(choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease choose what do you want to do about information");
        System.out.println("1.Show all item in system.");
        System.out.println("2.Show all people who lost item.");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        while(choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
            System.out.print("Please type between 1-2 : ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        switch(choice) {
        case 1 : 
            //input.close();
            showItem();
            break;
        case 2 : 
            //input.close();
            showPerson();
            break;
        default : System.out.println("What?");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Turning off program...");
        //input.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

The main method is nothing than just called chooseOption method.